# Create info bubble in wicket?

Tags: wicket, bubble-popup

Is there a way to create info bubbles in wicket. I would imagine for instance a ? as a small round image and when hovered-over, it would pop out a bubble with some text/images/stuff in it. A bit like a ModalWindow actually but which would be shown and hidden by hovering on a question mark and which would appear nearby the question mark. Is there a known component to do that or do I have to create my own modal window which is reacting to hovering states ?

Comment: If you end up rolling your own (as Visural's doesn't work with IE out of the box), I recommend qTip2.  Rolled my own with that and am quite pleased with the results.

Comment: Why would it need to be a modal window? Can it not be just a `<div>` with absolute positioning?

Comment: good point biziclop. thanks for your answer. jbrookover could you show me some code for that please ? Do you know why Visural doesnt work on IE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below link for sample tooltip for wicket

http://wicket.visural.net/examples/tooltips

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's looks nice ! Have you tested it on IE ? As jbrookover suggested that it doesnt work on it ...

Comment: No i havent, i dont have ie on my OS but if you have just locate to the demo site and try it if does not. However, that sound very unlikely to me.

Comment: Sadly, this URL is now a dead end. :'(

Answer (score 1):

I am a happy user of jQuery and for tooltips (that may contain any HTML content) I use jQuery Tools : http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

You can wrap the jQuery in a component with a header contributer, together with and the (html?) tooltip and the question mark.